# Why shell test with -o seems return a wrong result?

Tags: shell

I am a newbie. I have read the man doc of test, and it say

> EXPRESSION1 -o EXPRESSION2
>
> either EXPRESSION1 or EXPRESSION2 is true

I run this in my shell:

```
[ false -o false ] && echo "what happened?"
```

and it print the string, why? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [man test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

> -n STRING
>     the length of STRING is nonzero
>
> STRING
>   equivalent to -n STRING

The `false` is interpreted as a string. So `[ false -o false ]` is `[ -n false -o -n false ]`. As the string `false` has non-zero length (has 5 characters) the expression is true.

Answer (score 2):

`false` in a `test` statement is just a string, and non-empty strings are truthy. Conversely:

```
$ false && false && echo 'Nope'
$ echo $?
1
```